# Sending a textbox string from one form to a listbox in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have uploaded my code below. The problem I am facing is trying to get the text from the textBox1 & textBox2 in form2 into the listBox in form1. When the user opens the 2nd form, they should place text into the textboxes and upon clicking the button - it should close the form2 and insert the text into form1's listBox

I have tried multiple things but I can't seem to do it. I am also quite new to c# coding and have just started on windows forms so any help would be much appreciated.

**FORM 1 CODE BELOW**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToDoList
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> _items = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            _items.Add("TITLE\t\t\tDESCRIPTION\t\t\t\t\t\tPRIORITY\tDUE DATE");
            listBox1.DataSource = _items;


        }

        private void filesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**FORM 2 CODE BELOW**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToDoList
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        List<string> _items = new List<string>();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string tbtext)
        {
            //Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            //form1.listBox1.Items.Add(tbtext);
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            _items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            _items.Add(textBox2.Text);
            _items.Add(comboBox1.Text);

            form1.listBox1.DataSource = null;
            form1.listBox1.DataSource = _items;

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {






            //IF THE USER DOES NOT ENTER items IN THE SPACES THESE IF STATEMENTS BRING A MESSAGEBOX 
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox2.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill The Entries");

            }

            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Task Name");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox2.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Description");
                }
            }
        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you are creating a new Form1 in your Form2, this Form1 is never shown  and is not the same one that created your Form2. I would use ShowDialog to show Form2, that way it will be Modal and you can use a property to access the data once Form2 closes.

Comment: As Mark stated, ShowDialog is what you want.  This will give you a result (example: user clicked ok or cancel) and based on that result, form 1 can access the property from form 2 as needed.  See the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm not really getting the grips of this, so firstly I should change form2.show(); to form2.ShowDialog(); ? Thanks for your help by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea is correct, but what you must understand is what Mark stated in comments.  Creating `Form1` in `Form2` and adding data to that form won't work, because once `Form2` closes, that instance of `Form1` no longer exists.  I.E. What you are currently doing looks like this as a tree hierarchy:

> ```
> Form1 (open Form2)
>   |
>   +-> Form2 (open and save to Form1)
>         |
>         +-> Form1 (contains saved data but you never see it)
> ```

The original `Form1` is the parent.  It is responsible for opening `Form2`.  Using `ShowDialog`, `Form1` may know how `Form2` closed.  And because it is the parent form, it can access any public properties on `Form2`.  So say `Form2` has the following **public** fields:

```
public TextBox textBox1;
public TextBox textBox2;
```

You could then retrieve data from these like so:

```
public void SomeMethodInForm1()
{
   Form2 form2 = new Form2();

   // Show form2 as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK. 
   if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of form2's TextBox. 
      this._items.Add(form2.textBox1.Text);
      this._items.Add(form2.textBox2.Text);

      this.listBox1.DataSource = null;
      this.listBox1.DataSource = _items;
   }

   form2.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for the explanation too! I really appreciate it :)